# Laptop cannot reach pi via wifi

Tags: networking, wifi

So I want login to a pi2 (lets call it *pi-wifi*) with a dongle.
I got it up and running  with a display and it's connected to my local network.
*pi-wifi* cannot reach my laptop (also on wifi). `ping LAPTOPIP` will give an `Destination Host Unreachable`. When my laptop tries to ping to *pi-wifi* I get the same error.

But *pi-wifi* can ping/ssh to my other 2 pi's which are connected by cable ( *pi-lan1* and *pi-lan2*). And the *pi-lan1&2* can ping/ssh to *pi-wifi*

Logging in to the router shows all devices with the correct IP's. There is only 1 router/modem. and are all on `192.168.2.*` range

`ifconfig` gives the same *Bcast* and *Mask* ip's for all devices.

**laptop ifconfig**

```
enp6s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 40:16:7e:94:27:c2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 207268  bytes 12785101 (12.7 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 207268  bytes 12785101 (12.7 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp5s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.2.7  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
    inet6 fe80::a77d:88fe:d3b3:33c3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether ac:7b:a1:a2:75:f1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 2621542  bytes 3835755115 (3.8 GB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 1013988  bytes 105752553 (105.7 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**pi-wifi ifconfig**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:e4:b9:84  
      inet6 addr: fe80::bbf7:36b4:e257:976f/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:265 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:265 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:21944 (21.4 KiB)  TX bytes:21944 (21.4 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0b:81:9a:fc:98  
      inet addr:192.168.2.5  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::c0c2:e405:8001:aaf/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:212579 errors:0 dropped:25818 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:88078 errors:0 dropped:467 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:319399718 (304.6 MiB)  TX bytes:8721532 (8.3 MiB)
```

**pi-lan1 ifconfig** (*pi-lan2* is the same except the inet addr

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:21:d7:ef  
      inet addr:192.168.2.90  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::ba27:ebff:fe21:d7ef/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:2877337 errors:0 dropped:109 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2839529 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:254526958 (242.7 MiB)  TX bytes:285419630 (272.1 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:31 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:31 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:3376 (3.2 KiB)  TX bytes:3376 (3.2 KiB)
```

So for a workaround I log in to *pi-lan1* and then login to *pi-wifi* but that sucks.

Where do I start looking to fix this problem?

Comment: You could start by actually explaining your problem! What does `ifconfig` show on each Pi? Try actually including the commands you used.

Comment: I added the `ifconfig` results and rephrased my question a bit to clarify.  I simply want to login by ssh to _pi-wifi_ from my laptop.